# MongoDB: How to make sure that Javascript is waiting for processes?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, benchmarking, wait, measurement

I asked myself, whether javascript (concerning mongoDB) waits for the execution of mongoDB processes.

For example:

Im inserting documents like

```
for (i=0; i<=myarray.length -1; i++)
{
        db.mycol.insert(myarray[i]);
}
```

If I check the col status directly after that only see a few documents in the db or even 0. (e.g. instead of 100 only 29 or 0). When I execute the sleep() function with e.g. sleep(10000) I can see all may inserted documents.

So my question is, how can I make sure, that javascript waits for the complete insert? Or how can I measure that? At the moment I'm using

```
start = new Date().getTime();

for (i=0; i<=myarray.length -1; i++)
{
        db.mycol.insert(myarray[i]);
}
end = new Date().getTime();
time = end - start;
```

But if the insert-process isn't completed, the measurement of that function seems senseless to me.

edit:

by using `db.getLastError({w:1});`

I receive to following error:

uncaught exception: getlasterror failed: {
        "singleShard" : "replica2/ip:port,ip:port",
        "n" : 0,
        "lastOp" : NumberLong("5824731790958395692"),
        "connectionId" : 111744,
        "assertion" : "wrong type for field (w) 3 != 2",
        "assertionCode" : 13111,
        "errmsg" : "db assertion failure",
        "ok" : 0
}
failed to load: ... myscript.js

Comment: Why are you benchmarking it from the client side and not the database side? That's quite a useless test and I'm not sure what it proves, but yes sleep() is the normal way to do this.

Comment: How would I measure it from the database side? Why is it useless?

Comment: Because you are trying to measure the speed of a database operation from client code, to measure it from the database side you can turn on profiling: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to wait until MongoDB has written the data you can call [`getLastError`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/commands/#getLastError) with whatever options you're looking to wait for.

Like this:

```
start = new Date().getTime();
for (i=0; i<=myarray.length -1; i++) {
    db.mycol.insert(myarray[i]);
}
db.getLastError({w:1});
end = new Date().getTime();
time = end - start;
```

Comment: you could call db.getLastError() after each insert, but of course that will make things *much* slower.

Answer (score 1):

try this: `db.getLastError({w: majority});`

Comment: hi, I receive: ReferenceError: majority is not defined ...myscript.js:74

Comment: I have a sharding set, that consists of two replicasets, each 1 prim, 1 sec and 1 arb

Comment: `db.getLastError({w: 6});`

Comment: also you could try to set `w : all_members - all_arbiters`